# JDK 1.8 critical update /security patch

Tags: oracle, java-8, java-security

This is about Oracle's critical update

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpujul2015-2367936.html#AppendixJAVA

Is it possible to know what was the real security vulnerabilities  existed and what code changes has been made to fix these by downloading OpenJDK source code?

if I check the CVE details mostly it says "Unspecified vulnerability in Oracle Java SE 6u95, 7u80, and 8u45".

When it says 6u95,7u80 are affected, does it mean earlier versions (6u31,7u55) are also affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to know<sup>1</sup>.  Ask Oracle.  You probably need a support contract though, and you may be required to sign non-disclosure, etc agreements.

The other thing you could do is to wait until the corresponding patches have made it into the publicly accessible OpenJDK source-code base.

---

Oracle are being cagey about this for the same reasons that other software manufacturers are cagey about vulnerabilities.  They are trying to protect their customers by making it harder for the bad guys to craft exploits.  More significantly, there is always a risk that Oracle (or whoever) have missed something.

---

> When it says 6u95,7u80 are affected, does it mean earlier versions (6u31,7u55) are also affected?

You should assume so.  If that is not a good enough answer, then contact Oracle.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, this is based on supposition, but I'm pretty sure that a "sufficiently valuable Java customer" with a demonstrable "need to know" would be granted access to this kind of information.</sup>

Comment: so as of today OpenJDK source code having these fixes are not available right? I tried searching but I could not find it .

Comment: @user1493834 - That's why I said wait until they are available!

Comment: Also , what about this question? When it says 6u95,7u80 are affected, does it mean earlier versions (6u31,7u55) are also affected?

Comment: read @StephenCs answer "You should assume so. If that is not a good enough answer, then contact Oracle."